# There's a problem with [problem]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

The [problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem) tag is impossibly, uselessly vague. Any question posted on this site is *implicitly* a "problem"! The questions under this tag have nothing at all in common, beyond that many of them are rather low-quality.

Can we please burninate and/or blacklist this tag? It's useless.

Comment: Yes, we'll have to use the "question" tag instead.

Comment: Kill it with fire.

Comment: Agreed. The tags are supposed to help narrow down sub-fields so that people knowledgeable in them can find questions easier and help more people. Problem, Question, Help: they're all pretty useless to that effect.

Comment: The two questions (y'all probably nuked the rest) i see tagged as "question" are in fact meta-questions.  Someone attempting to use that tag should be guided to the meta site.

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: There are no more question tagged as [problem], what's next?

Comment: Perhaps we should use the euphemism, "challenge?"

Comment: Maybe you should just kill all the questions with that tag on them also, it might clean things up a bit.

Comment: At least it's not a [doubt] tag.

Comment: Replace with [Houston]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this tag was cleaned up in 2016. If it shows up again, remove it on sight.